# Python: filtering a list of custom objects, by one of its dictionary attributes

Tags: python, dictionary, object, filter, attributes

I am trying create a method within my class that has the ability to filter a list of objects in this class by one of its dictionary attributes.  For example:

In the class Vehicle I created below, the *category* parameter will be given a dictionary of key: value combinations, where the value will be 1 if the Vehicle fits that category, i.e.:

```
{'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}
```

So with my class Vehicle, I could create a list of car objects:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, category, price):
        self.__name = name
        self.__category = category
        self.__price = price 

lst_cars = 
[
Vehicle('Viper', {'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}, 300,000), 
Vehicle('x150', {'convertible': 0, 'pickup': 1, 'electric': 0}, 300,000), 
Vehicle('BMW', {'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}, 300,000)
]
```

I can sort my list by name using attrgetter and passing name as property with the following code:

```
def order_by(lst_cars, property):
    lst = []
    c = sorted(lst_cars, key=attrgetter(prop))
    for car in c:
        lst += [car]
    return lst
```

But what I really want is a method `parse_by(lst_cars, lst_category)` that takes a list of Vehicle objects and a as well as a list of category strings `['convertible', 'electric']` and it will return a list of objects that have a 1 for those category values.

```
[
Vehicle('Viper', {'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}, 300,000), 
Vehicle('BMW', {'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}, 300,000)
]
```

After playing with my code a little I came up with the following that seemed to work, so edited with an answer but others below were also helpful:

```
def parse_by(lst_cars, lst_category):
    c = lst_cars
    for item in lst_category:
        c = list(filter(lambda x: x.category[item] == 1, c))
    return c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simply example of what you are probably looking for. There are for sure more efficient solutions, but this should help you for now. Note that I deleted the `__` in front of your attributes to access them from outside with my function. Otherwise you will have to write something like `obj._Vehicle__category` instead of `obj.category` to access them.

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, category, price):
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.price = price

lst_cars = [
Vehicle('Viper', {'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}, 300.000),
Vehicle('x150', {'convertible': 0, 'pickup': 1, 'electric': 0}, 300.000),
Vehicle('BMW', {'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}, 300.000)
]

def parse_by(lst_cars, lst_category):
    output = lst_cars.copy()
    for attr in lst_category:
        for obj in output:
            if not obj.category.get(attr):
                output.remove(obj)
    return output


for x in parse_by(lst_cars, ['convertible', 'electric']):
    print(x.name)
#Viper
#BMW
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this,

- Define `parse_by(lst_cars = [], lst_category = [])` within `Vehicle` class which return boolean value based based on search filter. `__` makes the variable private and will not be visible outside, it will be accessible just from inside the own class.

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, category, price):
        self.__name = name
        self.__category = category
        self.__price = price

    def parse_by(self, lst_cars, lst_category):
        if self.__name in lst_cars and \
                all(self.__category.get(c) for c in lst_category):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        return f"name : {self.__name}, cateogry : {self.__category} price : {self.__price}"
```

- Use list comprehension to filter the values.

```
lst_cars = [
    Vehicle('Viper', {'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}, 300000),
    Vehicle('x150', {'convertible': 0, 'pickup': 1, 'electric': 0}, 300000),
    Vehicle('BMW', {'convertible': 1, 'pickup': 0, 'electric': 1}, 300000)
]

print(
    [str(x) for x in lst_cars if x.parse_by(['Viper', 'BMW'], ['convertible'])]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_by(lst_cars, lst_category):
    validCars = []
    for car in lst_cars:
         if all([car.getattr(attr) for attr in lst_category]): #any applies logical ANDs on all elements in list
            validCars.append(car)
    return validCars
```

`[car.getattr(attr) for attr in lst_category]` this creates a list of values for all the categories (attributes) for a particular car in lst_cars.